# Mismatch of equations and variables in modelica microgrid model

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am getting an error of 297 equations and 300 variables. Previous all of of my modelica buildings model have had a match. However, this time there is a mismatch, and I am not sure why. I redid the connections, but I am still getting the 297/300 error. Is there a way of debugging mismatched equation/variables in modelica other than redoing the model? Everything seems fine to me, but I am not sure why there is a mismatch. I uploaded an image of the model and its code to this post. Thank you for the help

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13oxasXd-8wH8nN97sRXpl_XeU5I4k5j5/view?usp=sharing

Edit:

Adding one side connection error:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a message regarding the singularity. Dymola outputs something like:

[image: Singularity error message]

The connection seems to be there, but it should be a connection with four variables. In the current model, only the first one is connected. Therefore, three equations are missing. You need to be careful to connect all variables when drawing the connection. In Dymola, this would look like this:

[image: Create vector connection]

The important part is to have colons (":") in the connection. The GUI should generate the respective code: `connect(multiplex4.y[:], peak_shaver.uR[:])`.

You could as well change the code manually. Both ways should result in  which replaces the original line which had ones instead of the colons.

This fixes the issue for me at least...

Comment: Ah Okay, this is strange. In my other code where I use a 3 input multiplexer, and I never used colons in the connection, and had no connection problems https://drive.google.com/file/d/13-lscabaN6jR76v-g_SyZ3gJALR-LwuO/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: Nevertheless, I still tried using colons for the conf_paper_microgrid model ,and got this error.: Wrong number of subscripts in BESS.SOC[:] (1 subscripts for 0 dimensions).
(I can only do that by inserting it in the code) One thing I wanted to mention is that you are getting an option to define both sides of the connection. I am only getting the option for one side, and I am not sure why. The only one that does is the one connected directly to the solar power sensor. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: I fixed the problem by only adding the colon to the  connect(multiplex4.y[:], peak_shaver.uR[:]), and not to the multiplexers input. I am not sure why the colon is only needed for the multiplex out and python module. I have ran simulations without doing that for a 3 input multiplexer. I am not sure why that is the case. Thank you for the help.